# What are these "Expectation failed" messages in VS2010 PGO and how do I fix them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pgo

When I perform the PGO optimization step (using `LINK.EXE /LTCG:PGU`), the Visual Studio 2010 linker complains:

```
Merging foo!1.pgc
'FOO_EDGE::get_input': Arc 2 --> 4 has negative count (-414343)
Expectation failed: f line 4241
'FOO_DELAY::set_delay': Block 18 outgoing counts differ from block count (-9 diff)
Expectation failed: f line 4261
Expectation failed: f line 4211
'FOO_DELAY::set_delay': Arc 12 --> 23 has negative count (-3)
Expectation failed: f line 4220
Generating code
907 of 4948 ( 18.33%) profiled functions will be compiled for speed
4948 of 4948 functions (100.0%) were optimized using profile data
42912225037 of 42912225037 instructions (100.0%) were optimized using profile data
```

What's causing these "expectation failures"?  How should I address them?  It seems like PGO is still optimizing the code, but I'm a little suspicious of the quality/completeness of the optimizations in the presence of these messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these errors occur when performing PGO-instrumented runs of multithreaded applications.  They can be avoided by *compiling* (not *linking*) with the `/PogoSafeMode` flag on x64.

I didn't find the [MSDN documentation on this flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee390848.aspx) particularly clear; the correct procedure for performing PGO on multithreaded code is:

1. Compile with `cl.exe /PogoSafeMode`
2. Link with `link.exe /LTCG:PGI`
3. Execute your multithreaded profiling run(s)
4. Re-link with `link.exe /LTCG:PGO`